# Why are we using a past modal verb with a present verb in this sentence?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, present-tense

> it is typically restricted to military aircraft except for the
> legendary Concorde, which was able to speeds of up to three times that
> of passenger planes today

Why are we using 'was able to' with 'speeds'
Was able to = past modal
Speed-s=present verb

Comment: It's ungrammatical. There is probably a word missing. Can you check the source?

Answer (score 2):

**This is very likely a misprint.**

The sentence as written is not grammatical. The most likely fix is that there is a missing word before "speeds". Good candidates for the missing word are "achieve" or "reach" or various synonyms.

This would make "speeds" not a present tense verb but a plural noun.

"Speeds of up to..." is a very common noun phrase.

There are other less likely solutions, which require more changes, such as "was able to speed [along at] up to three times [the speed of] passenger planes today.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a missing word, the past tense is used in

> Concorde ***was*** able to [achieve] speeds of...

because it no longer flies. The 'feature' (ultrasonic speed?) is still used, so

> it ***is*** typically restricted to military aircraft

using the present tense.